# Is it necessary to convert variables into real terms when using time fixed effects?

Tags: regression, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

I have a panel dataset spanning 5 years. I'm interested in the impact a independent variable has on a dependent variable whose value is measured in dollars while controlling for a variety of factors.

I know that my independent variable is correlated with time, it increases over time, and I know that my dependent variable measured in $ also would increase over time due to inflation leading to omitted variable bias.

I am including time fixed effects in my regression to eliminate this bias but it was suggested to me to also convert my dependent variable into real terms using CPI. CPI is somewhat inaccurate and would result in some distortion of my dependent variable, although it would correct for the issue of inflation.

Do I need to convert the dependent variable into real terms if I'm already holding time fixed effects? My intuition would be no, since the omitted variable changes over time but not entity so it shouldn't bias my results but I could be wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In general, you'd prefer real terms to nominal terms, because a) nominal terms have additional variation due to changing inflation rates and b) modeling nominal terms means, in effect, constructing a model of inflation and another model for the real effect, only jumbled together.  Even a mild inaccuracy in CPI is typically worth it to get rid of these two problems.

Comment: By including time effects in your fixed effects regression, you would capture also (time) effects non-related to the general inflation of the currency unit at hand. Think of shocks in certain markets kicking in in a specific period and the like. That said, you could do both. Also there are stastical tests to see if including the time effects in the regression makes a difference.